# Light dispersion/diffraction model for optical measurement system

Tags: optics, visible-light, dispersion

in a project of mine I have to model the dispersion effect (through a grating) of light in the context of a camera based measurement system.

Imagine the following setup:
[image: Setup]

Left to right: collimated light source (white here); diffraction grating; three examples of diffracted parts of the light; cylindrical diffusing lens

In the column below, the expected cross-section (dotted line) is shown.

How can I formally (mathematically) describe a setup like this?
Do I use a ray model or a wave model of light?
Are the cross-section expectations likely to happen in a real system?
Are there diffraction gratings that might combine the two optical elements ? (a cylindrical reflective diffraction grating maybe)

I am interested in placing a camera in far right part of the setup, to detect if the light source is blue, green, or red.

I greatly appreciate any kind of advice!!

Comment: I'm sorry no one ever answered or even commented.I would build a working model and measure the distances, light, lens, everything and revise your question. That will help get your answer.